# Using GREP to produce table from Database File (.pdb)

Tags: grep

What I have is a folder with PDB files which contain information in the following pattern:

```
*HEADER 'protein date ID'
TITLE  'title of document here
AUTHOR ' the authors listed here' 
AUTHOR ' continued..'
SOURCE 'source organism (s)'
SOURCE 'continued'
SOURCE 'continued'
COMPND 'compound or complex studied'
COMPND 'continued'
```

As you can see the source and other information that is in this file expands to multiple lines. I want to create a single table with this information in these PDB files using the GREP command. I have not been able to group the multiple lines into one and and produce a table with columns such as TITLE, AUTHOR, SOURCE...etc

My reason for this is to be able to present in a table information from PDB files and filter through new research by author or source, which will save LOTS of time on the actual website.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `grep` is the right tool, I'd suggest `sed` or `awk`. Here's a `sed` solution (or maybe not a complete solution, depending on your desired output):

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};:s;s/\nSOURCE//2;ts' file.pdb
```

It only processes the lines with `SOURCE` though.

Here's a more generic version:

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};:s;s/\(\n[A-Z]\+\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/;ts' file.pdb
```